# Adding and displaying data on button click android

Tags: android

> I want to add data in my database on click of a button and I want to display data in a listview .I am making an app in which there is an edittext field and a button .If user enters name in the field and clicks button the data should get added in database and the listview also gets populate with data.I have posted my code which is using a cursor adapter,a listview to display data and a button to perform action .
>   I am also using cursor loaders.I have implemented basic functions of cursor loader.

```
Here is my xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.nitikakamboj.drawapp.MainActivity">
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="16dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal">
         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/name_field"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="Enter Name"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/add_button"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="add"/>
       </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_name"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Name in List"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            />
       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_below="@id/no_name"></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my main java code**
I have posted my code which is using a cursor adapter,a listview to display data and a button to perform action .
I am also using cursor loaders.I have implemented basic functions of cursor loader.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
      private EditText mNameEditText;
      NameCursorAdapter nameCursorAdapter;
       SQLiteDatabase database;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         final ListView nameListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        nameCursorAdapter=new NameCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,null);
        nameListView.setAdapter(nameCursorAdapter);
        mNameEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_field);

        Button mAddButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
           String name=  mNameEditText.getText().toString();
            if(name.length()>0)
            {

            }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
       String projection[]={NameEntry._ID,
       NameEntry.COLUMN_NAME};
        return new CursorLoader(this,NameEntry.BASE_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
          nameCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
          nameCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that from XML alone...

Comment: I know that I have implemented code creating database,setting providers and main activity code.I posted my xml file so that one can get clear idea of what i want to do in UI.

Comment: I have no idea of how to update database on clicking button and add data to listview.I need help for that only.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do anywhere without taking a peek at the code and understanding what you're doing and what you're doing wrong; The XML alone simply tells me which Views to expect to see in the code, but not what you're doing with them or what's being loaded into the list. Maybe the problem is in your `Adapter`, maybe it's in the `add_button`'s `OnClickListener` or somewhere else. I can't presume but as it is, I cant really help

Comment: I am asking for general steps only .

Comment: You'll need a `CursorAdapter` for your `ListView`.

Comment: I am using CursorAdapter

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to grab a reference to your XML button in your activity's `onCreate` method:

```
Button mAddButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button);
```

Then, add an OnClickListener:

```
mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do database stuff here, for example: grab text from EditText and save to DB table.
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you click the button, that OnClickListener will run the code to save your data.

Happy coding!

Comment: Actually i know that database stuff will go in on click method.Can you please explain what kind of stuff I need to do?

Comment: @NitikaKamboj you need to know how to do database transactions? Read this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html